# If I were to move this profile picture element (within the pink box in image) would the downward facing arrow remain in the right side?

Tags: gui-design, ux-field

If I were to move this profile picture element (within the pink box in image) would the downward facing arrow remain in the right side? Or to the left? [image]

Answer (score 0):

If the chevron's direction in the example would be right instead of down, [I would say this question is a duplicate](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/122632/is-there-any-logic-when-arrows-are-used-before-or-when-after-the-content).

However, I believe there's no right or wrong answer for this question, but I'd love sharing my 2 cents.

Chevron looking down indicates the user that it will open a submenu right below the chevron. Chevron down icons are usually used in accordions to collapse the content and they usually go after the label. I believe that logic behind that is in most countries people read the text from left to right, so it is more convenient to perceive the logic this way:

Title -> Action

In your case "Title" is profile picture and "Action" is a chevron icon indicating that the profile content could be collapsed.

[image]

As I've mentioned, the answer depends on your audience and the way they tend to read and perceive information.

#### Is chevron down icon really necessary?

Many applications like Google, Instagram, Facebook, Adobe are using similar way of showing authenticated user and none of them are using chevron down icon to indicate that user could collapse the content. These companies have definitely done their homework on user research and I believe that their audiences understand that profile content could be collapsed without the chevron icon. If your audience is aware of Google, Facebook, or even Adobe then in that case you should consider removing the icon.